# backbone.hammer.js, event is not fired second time

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-routing, hammer.js

The following button click works only in page load, not after routing.
1) display default page
2) Click the "click here" button (This works)
3) Click some other button to route (without reload the page, clear the content, and create a new view give option to route back to the default page)
4) Click the option to move back to the default.
5) Without reload redraw the defult page again.
6) Click the "click here" button **(This is not working)**

Here is the code

```
var LPRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.pageContent = $('#pageContent');
    },

    routes: {
        'AA': 'routerMethod',
        '': 'defaultMethod'
    },

    defaultMethod: function () {
        //TODO: Set page title.

        var self = this;

        self.pageContent.empty();

        if (!self.someView) {
            self.someView = new SomeView();
            self.someView.render();
        }

        self.pageContent.append(self.someView.el);

        /*
        Create a view with some link or button which will redirect to routerMethod.
        */
    },

    routerMethod : function() {
        this.pageContent.empty();
        /*
            Create a view with some link or button which will redirect to defaultMethod.
        */

    }

});

var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    className: "someclass",

    initialize: function (options) {

    },

    hammerEvents: {
        'tap .innerclass': 'someMethod'
    },

    someMethod: function (e) {
        alert("did you click me?");
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.append("<div class='innerclass'><input type='button' value='click here'/></div>");
        return this;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your render function will create a new button each time, so the event - which was bound to the original button element - is not bound to the new button element.  You can use the delegateEvents() method to rebind the events hash - http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

Comment: But I'm checking the view object already exist or not, based on that only I'm creating new object.

Comment: And why delegate?, I am using hammerEvents.

Comment: I planned to remove the view and re-render it.